# internal BGP routing through two AS with the same routing policy

Tags: networking, routes, network-protocols

[image]

In this question I can easily see why a and c are using eBGP. However, why is b and d iBGP instead of OSPF and RIP respectively?

Thanks

Edit: This is an excerpt from Computer Networking by Kurose and Ross.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://www.enterprisenetworkingplanet.com/netsp/article.php/3617346/Networking-101--Understanding-iBGP.htm) should answer all your questions.

Answer (score 0):

This is a horrendous example, because it doesn't detail which nodes are actually speaking iBGP ( nor the 'why' ), but the reason b and d get the information from iBGP is because the prefix has no method to make it into the IGP.  This could change easily though if you configured the EBGP speaking nodes to redistribute the eBGP learned routes into their respective IGPs ( OSPF and RIP respectively )